# How to render chosen fields in form symfony/twig?

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony

I try to render a few fields in my form, not all, but twig always render all fields. It is my twig code:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{form_widget(form.subject)}}
{{form_widget(form.name)}}
{{form_widget(form.parent,{'value' : ''})}}
{{form_widget(form.save)}}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: because you have defined all the fields in `FormType.php` try comment your fields in form builder , also define fields which needs to be appear in twig.

Comment: Pass the render_rest option to false to the form_end function

Comment: `{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}` that's what @Matteo said

Comment: Set type to hidden for fields you don't want to show  hiddenType:class in formType

Answer (score 1):

Set type for field you don't want visible to hidden. your form type would look something like this:

```
class ConfigurationFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', HiddenType::class)
           // more fields
    }

  // other configurations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `form_end` function renders the elements that have not been rendered yet. Read here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables.

> This helper also outputs form_rest() unless you set render_rest to
>   false

You can disable that behaviour as you can see in the docs.

Anyway you should render all fields for validation to work, for example, and for security reasons (as it will add validation for CSRF automatically).